# DataTables - Add Expandable Details for each row

Tags: jquery, arrays, datatable, datatables

I need to add Expandable Detail for each row of my datatable like here :

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html

I have this HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_1">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>User Name</th>
         <th>Adresse IP Utilisateur</th>
         <th>Pseudo Utilisateur</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

This Javascript ajax witch returns me datas that I need to put in my table :

```
function liste_erreurs_sql() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/administration/log_mysql/script/recuperation_erreurs_sql.php",
        dataType:"JSON",
        type:"GET",
        success: function(err){
                autocomplete_tableau_err(err.tableau_erreurs_mysql);
        }
    });
```

AJAX array :
[image: Ajax Array information]

This Javascript for DataTAbles :

```
 function autocomplete_tableau_err(tab_err) {
  $('#sample_1').dataTable().fnClearTable();
  $('#sample_1').dataTable().fnDestroy();
  $('#sample_1').dataTable({
     "bDeferRender": true,
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bPaginate": true,
     "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
     "bSort": true,
     "iDisplayLength": 10,
     "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
     "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true},
      { "bSortable": true},
      { "bSortable": true},
      { "bSortable": true},
    ],
    }
  });
```

Autocomplete my table with ajax information :

```
 $.each(tab_err, function (index,value){
       $('#sample_1').dataTable().fnAddData( [
          tab_err[index].date_erreur_sql, 
          tab_err[index].user_name, 
          tab_err[index].adresse_ip_utilisateur, 
          tab_err[index].pseudo_utilisateur, ]
        );
```

Here is my problem ... how can I add expandable details ?

I try two solutions but I have for each a lot of errors ...
 the most efficiant :

```
$.each(tab_err, function (index,value){
       $('#sample_1').dataTable().fnAddData( [
          tab_err[index].date_erreur_sql, 
          tab_err[index].user_name, 
          tab_err[index].adresse_ip_utilisateur, 
          tab_err[index].pseudo_utilisateur, ]
        );


        /* Formatting function for row details */
        function format (tab_err) {
// `tab_err` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Full name:</td>'+
        '<td>'+tab_err[index].user_name+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
        '<td>'+tab_err[index].pseudo_utilisateur+'</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
        '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
'</table>';
```

}

```
  });

        //Insert a 'details' column to the table
        var nCloneTh = document.createElement( 'th' );
        var nCloneTd = document.createElement( 'td' );
        nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<span class="row-details icon-plus-sign2"></span>';

        $('#sample_1 thead tr').each( function () {
            this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
        } );

        $('#sample_1 tbody tr').each( function () {
            this.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
        } );



   /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
         * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
         * rather it is done here
         */
        $('#sample_1').on('click', ' tbody td .row-details', function () {
            var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
            var oTable = $('#sample_1').dataTable();
            if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
            {
                /* This row is already open - close it */
                $(this).addClass("icon-plus-sign2").removeClass("icon-minus-sign-alt");
                oTable.fnClose( nTr );
            }
            else
            {
                /* Open this row */                
                $(this).addClass("icon-minus-sign-alt").removeClass("icon-plus-sign2");
                oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
            }
        });
```

ERROR : `Uncaught ReferenceError: fnFormatDetails is not defined`

Comment: Write `fnFormatDetails()` outside of `$.each()`!

Comment: perfect ! it works but how can I complete my "row details" with information from ajax in relation with the row  ? with a each ?